# Polish letter Encoding issue in Internet explorer 8

Tags: java, encoding, polish

I m search utility by entering polish letter in my web application.

if i m entering polish letter as **Łódź** it will search data from database in firefox but not in IE 8.

in same way i will append search criteria of entered value and display in curretn criteria panel it will show different word.

i m using ajax call for search function.

also used UTF-8 ,ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-2 for solve this issue but still no change.

when i entered **Łódź** it will show in criteria panel as below.

```
firefox: ÅÃ³dÅº
internet explorer: LÃ³dz
```

Please suggest.

Thanks.
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

How about ISO-8859-15? I normally use that in Java on Windows when dealing with European languages.